# Store all different files after command 'svn status'

Tags: svn

My question is after "svn status -qu", there are some files which may be modified or added or ...

I am wondering how I can store these files in a different directory (for sure NOT one by one).

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? Do you want to copy any files that have been modified to another directory? Are you trying to store files that have been modified in case you decide to revert? Why not simply do another checkout?

Comment: @DavidW. Thanks for your reply. What I want to do is to copy all the modified or added files to another directory. Because at this stage of my code, I am not sure if it is the right time to commit them on my branch.

Comment: Make a private branch of the public branch just for yourself using `svn cp`. Then, check in the stuff on this _private branch_. If you find our you need to do the commit, just merge your _private branch_ to the public branch.

Comment: Yes, Actually I am working on my branch. and I know on of the purpose of using branch is what I want. but I want to store every progress in another directory on my local disk as well. for this purpose I do svn status and then I cp every M or A file in my local directory one by one. I am wonderying if there is a way doing this at one command

Comment: If you insist, you could write a shell script that does a `svn status` and then takes each entry and copies that path to another directory. When you call the shell script, it could copy everything for you as if it's a single command. Would this work for you?

Comment: yes thanks, It actually is what I want, but I do not know how to write the script.